# I am having trouble with jquery modal with multiple id's

Tags: jquery, html

I am completely new to jQuery and I have the following script from jquery library. On a single page i have multiple link that when user clicks on it, a dialogue message pops up. So far this is my code. My question is what if I have about 30 links on a single page, should i create a new jquery function over and over again with different ids? How?

```
<script>
         $(function() {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
        }
        });
        $( "#opener1" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
        });

         $(function() {
        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
        }
        });
        $( "#opener2" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
        });
    </script>
```

I also have the following html

```
<div title="click to view details">
                <a href="#" class="p1" rel="nofollow" aria-haspopup="false" id="opener1"></a>
                    <p id="dialog1">
                        <strong>Monkey</strong>Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails.
                    </p>
                        <b class="b1"></b>
            </div>
            <div title="click to view details">
                <a href="#" class="p2" rel="nofollow" aria-haspopup="false" id="opener2"></a>
                    <p id="dialog2">
                        <strong>Vulture</strong>A particular characteristic of many vultures is a bald head, devoid of normal feathers.
                    </p>
                        <b class="b2"></b>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 ways to accomplish this task.
Probably the best is to use classes, so you use the same class on links you want to manage, and then you use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind actions to them.
Another way could be the use of the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function on the `a` tag. I don't think that in your case this is the best solution, but it's just to say that in some circumstances you can use this solution, too.

Comment: but i don't know how to do it :(

Comment: I think that with [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vm34p/) you can understand. Anyway the class selector documentation it's clear, just check the explanation and the examples in that page.