# Bootstrap: How to prevent modal dialog stacking on top of open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog that triggers when someone exits the viewport, in an attempt to collect their email address. This is mostly due to a plugin called [Ouibounce](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce).

Now the problem is, there are a few other modals scattered around the page that trigger when a user clicks sign up or login.

If you have the signup/login modal open and exit the viewport with the signup/login still open, A 'unlock' modal immediately pops up over whatever modal is already open.

Is there a way to prevent modal stacking with a general JS attribute? I've tried manipulating the CSS but since both modals exist during the same page wide styles, there was little success.

Comment: Post your code so we can understand the question more clearly.a fiddle would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery simple multiple modals on one html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586148/jquery-simple-multiple-modals-on-one-html-page)                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24838926/i-am-having-trouble-with-jquery-modal-with-multiple-ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [callback function](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce#callback)

> You can add a callback, which is a function that will run once Ouibounce has been triggered, by using the `callback` option.

If you are using [bootstrap-modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), each bootstrpmodal has default `modal` class so no need to target each bootstrap modal `id` and bootstrap modal can be closed via JavaScript

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

which can be use and close all open modals (doesn't matter how many bootstrap modals opened) when `Ouibounce` will be triggered

```
ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
    callback: function() { 
        $('.modal').modal('hide'); //Close all open modals
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peghpmb3/)

How to check in fiddle: it's bit tricky to check in fiddle, 1st bring mouse cursor inside `result section` and then straight move the cursor up to `css section.`

Open bootstrap modal, if you like you can open new modal from old modal and then move the mouse cursor straight up to CSS section, `Ouibounce` modal will be triggered and bootstrap modal(s) will be closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this worked.